# Printing in ICCUBE

Tags: reporting, wkhtmltopdf, iccube, iccube-reporting

I am trying to setup printing functionality on icCube reporting. I have wkhtmltopdf installed and setup on my computer, .exe file is in my path. I updated the icCube.xml file like this:

```
<printComponentConfiguration active="true">

  <!--  <url>/icCube/print/*</url>-->
   <url>/icCube/print/*</url>
    <!--
        The path of the wkhtmltopdf (http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) executable; use an absolute path
        if it is not accessible from the icCube server process (i.e., in the PATH).
    -->
    <exec>C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf</exec>

    <!--
        (Seconds) Every housekeeping-period a job is running to cleanup timeout printing job(s).
    -->
    <houseKeepingPeriod>15</houseKeepingPeriod>

    <!--
        (Seconds) Elapsed time after which a printing job is considered as timed out (can be
        cancelled by the housekeeping job.
    -->
    <timeout>30</timeout>
```

iccCube server is started normally, but i still get this message when attempting to print report.

[image]

Has anyone had this problem and has some advice? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the "community" version, the print server is not available. Request an evaluation key if you'd like to evaluate the printing feature.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of time.